# Can you keep "you" out of hostile comments?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

Here's a transcript of comments under [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/25465/254):

> - This answer make sutta conflict themselves although the sutta never conflict in this case. If you use "sakko kāyo sakkāyo" in [Sakkāyasutta][6], Sakkāyasutta, which has only sakko, will conflict with Sacca-pabba of [Satipaṭṭhānasuttaṃ][5], which has both sakko and paro. – Bonn 9 hours ago
> - No. This is unrelated to what i posted. Just because there is external kaya does not mean 'sakkaya ditthi' refers to external kaya. 'Sakkaya' is not found in MN 10 **therefore your idea sounds very wrong & mistaken** – Dhammadhatu 7 hours ago
> - If you can not compare between Sutta. Saṃ. Kha. Sakkāyasutta, and MN 10 then mix it together, it means **you have not enough skill** to describe sakkāya-diṭṭhi. – Bonn 7 hours ago
> - **I just read someone refuting your mistakes on Dhammawheel. If you wish to debate, you should post there & not here. On Dhammawheel, i have never observed once your posts not shown to be wrong.** – Dhammadhatu 6 hours ago
> - **No one refuting me in Dhammawheel, they trying to understand what I am describing. They are not like you, don't decide them like that.dhammawheel.com/**… – Bonn 6 hours ago
> - **Also, you can debate me. So if you can do, why I can not act like you?** – Bonn 6 hours ago
> - **This forum is not for debating.** – Dhammadhatu 5 hours ago
> - **On DW, someone told you** sakkaya is not kayanupassana because sakkaya is dhammanupassana, – Dhammadhatu 5 hours ago
> - **Even though your quote still be uneducated debate.** I wrote "Sutta. Ma. Mū. Sacca-pabba of Satipaṭṭhānasuttaṃ". Saccapabba is in dhammānupassanā-satipaṭṭhāna, not kāyānupassanā-satipaṭṭhāna. **I wrote right, he read wrong, what I can do?** – Bonn 5 hours ago
> - Also, Sutta. Saṃ. Kha. Sakkāyasutta which I comparing to MN10 is talking about sacca-pabba in dhammānupassanāsatipaṭṭhāna. Why he refer to kāyānupassanāsatipaṭṭhāna? – Bonn 5 hours ago
> - **So your quote trying to distort my answer. Why? Because you love to debate, not to understand.** – Bonn 5 hours ago

I have highlighted:

- Phrases where someone comments on "you" instead of on the text
- Phrases which are a reply to a comment about you.

So,

- Don't you think the discussion would be better without "you"?
- Could you try to avoid criticising "you" in future, and stick to the text?

Also what should a moderator do with comments like these?

- Pretend to ignore that it seems partially hostile?
- Delete everything?
- Move it all to chat?
- Edit specific comments and delete others?

It's work but moderators are able to edit comments --

- See [When should moderators edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238095/139866)
- But see also [Modifying comments](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1634/254) which shows that even a small edit can confuse people.

Comment: Sorry, voted up by mistake. Force of habit.

Comment: Voted up by agreement :)

Answer (score 1):

I just skimmed it a bit and think you've handled it perfectly by moving it to a different page.

- Ignoring: no,
- Editing only some: no, there are two parties in a
  quarrel (at least),
- Deleting everything: no.

Plus this, I agree also with:

> When editing comments for tone, you should strive to make the smallest edit necessary to correct the problem. You should also generally leave a comment advising the comment's author against such faux pas in the future! Such commentary helps to avoid the appearance of deceit.