# Can admins edit comments?

Tags: discussion

Is someone here editing my comments? That is very creepy and "militant" if so!

I have brought it up with stackexchange in general; I hope it's nothing to do with them.

Comment: incidentally, a discussion i was having with a B. academic he asked me to stop cos he thought someone had hacked it. so probably off site. apologies

Comment: Recently saw an extremely egregious harsh 'comment' which didn't sound like the Asker, and which has apparently since disappeared, and also noticed an out of context feature in an answer by Asker; please ping/ contact this poster privately, so as to be sure and remain ontopic & in accordance with all site policies. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A moderator can do that, yes.

I don't remember doing so recently, but it's not impossible that I might have, there's been a lot to moderate today.

I generally don't -- if a comment needs editing (because it's hostile or something) I'd usually delete it instead.

If you'd like to reference a specific comment which you think might have been edited (post its URL), I can tell you whether somebody edited it.

---

Edit to add: I found the comment you were asking about. Yes Andrei edited it, changing "strike" to "murder" before answering it. Id don't know why -- maybe he was setting up a more convenient example to answer?

Anyway you deleted that comment.

When you delete a comment then the whole conversation (dialog) tends to stop making sense, people replying to since-deleted comment, so I clean up by deleting the remainder.

Comment: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/41314/how-do-buddhists-that-think-of-karma-figuratively-do-so-about-rebirth the comment to A. i was SURE was just about "striking" [zen] him, not murdering his daughter, i mean... if you can tell me of ANY edits?

Comment: lol phew, just creepy haha

Comment: Yeah that was a pretty ... ghastly example. The last time I remember editing a comment was [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1634/254) in 2015 -- that taught me it's quite "disorienting" to a user whose comment *changes*.

Comment: it's cool... you know, we may have competing opinions on buddhism, but, being in some sense buddhists -- even if satirical ones -- we are on the same side yeah :)

Comment: regrettably, that euphemistically described 'ghastly example' was Extremely pejorative & legally damaging to the person whose name it was deliberately made under, and when it disappeared seemed as censoring of the person whose name it was under; such material triggers internet monitors for illegal webcontent and website bans :(

Comment: Regarding subsequent comment dialog deletion, (unless something egregiously objectionable), maybe consider at times, rather than deletion of subsequent dialog, perhaps replacing something removed from within a comment with ~ 'content edited', or replacing a comment with ~ 'comment edited', and leaving possibly beneficial subsequent posts standing. Thank you for your conscientious & ongoing helpful contributions to the site.

Comment: @MH Thank you. If don't often censor *people*, but it's not unusual to delete a *comment* for one reason or another -- remember that, in theory, [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). And if someone deletes their own comment I don't think I should undelete that and replace it with "[comment deleted]" under their name -- I've never seen that done on other SE sites. Most people don't delete their own comments (but some people do sometimes).

Comment: Yes, which is very excellent; Thank you for the information about theoretical basis for comments: it seems on SE that comments are often utilised for helpful footnotes; & the possible suggestion wasnotintended re comments deleted by commenters themselves, which is often obvious from context, but rather for followup commenters to nothave to wonder what became of their comments re sitedeleted comments, & also as being anonymous rather than under posters' names; And, necessity of deletion of comments is hopefully unusual on this site anyway! Thank you for your kind & clarifying comment.

Comment: @MH Killing is sometimes a topic on this site, in the context of the first precept or karma -- it's not "illegal" in that context. But "ghastly" also means "ghostly" I can imagine the surprise (or horror -- ghostly, or "creepy" as the OP wrote) of writing "strike" (meaning one thing) and seeing your words silently changed to "murder" (meaning another). Not too frightening though, hopefully, after you understand how that might have happened.

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit disappointed nothing was done about this, which I why I left the site - the environment was toxic. and from a sincere person - let alone self defined enlightened being - really weird.